# how to upload file without select the file?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

How to upload a file without browsing the file? because I know where the file is, so i don't want to browse to it. I was trying the code below, but it didn't work.

```
 <form id="fupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="f" value="D:\\test.docx" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
 </form>
```

The attribute "value" seems didn't work with "input file" control. Then i tried with "src" attribute, but still the same. I wonder how can we do that? is it possible to upload a file by providing a specific file location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

That would be an incomprehensibly large security hole.

Comment: any solution to do? can i use flash to do that? if can, is there any reference? thanks :)

Comment: **No**.  That would also be an incomprehensibly large security hole.